# .htaccess file not working on godaddy server

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I updated my site [tutorialdata.com](http://tutorialdata.com) which uses .htaccess for redirecting rule. When I checked on localhost it works fine, but when I launch it does not work properly. Only a few pages are displayed properly, most of them show blank pages.

Code used for .htaccess

```
RewriteBase www.tutorialdata.com/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} examples/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)
RewriteRule ^examples/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ examples.php?action=pgm&l=$1&c=$2&s=$3&p=$4

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} examples/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)
RewriteRule ^examples/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ examples.php?action=subcat&l=$1&c=$2&s=$3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} examples/(.*)/(.*)
RewriteRule ^examples/(.*)/(.*)$ examples.php?action=cat&l=$1&c=$2
```

How can I remove this error?

Comment: what is your url structure, which url its coming as blank and which are not showing ?

Comment: http://www.tutorialdata.com/examples or http://www.tutorialdata.com/online-test are coming as blank and other than main page of tutorial are also display blank pages

Answer (score 0):

This has been posted similarly before so it is a duplicate but I will answer anyways.
I'm assuming you know how to enable the ModRewrite as your local server works correctly.
This may be the problem as possibly GoDaddy may not allow you to change the httpd.conf file.
If this is the case you will need to look at the GoDaddy FAQ and then contact their support for more information.

Comment: I might also add that you probably did this but didn't include it in the post, is that you added the line for `RewriteEngine on`